# Use logging.DEBUG in PyCharm debug run

Tags: python, logging, pycharm, python-logging

What is a good way to set the logging level for a module in pycharm so that debugging statements will print during a debug session? I am using the native python logging module in python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python logging level can be set inside the Python module, not outside from PyCharm. Your Python application must adjust its own logging level.

- Call `logging.getLogger()` to get the root logger (topmost in logging hierarchy)
- Set environment variable in your run configuration in PyCharm. Detect this using `os.environ.get("MYDEBUgVARNAME")` and then call `root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`. I am not sure if PyCharm itself sets any variable based on if it's normal or debug run.

For more information check my blog post for standard Python logging patters https://opensourcehacker.com/2016/05/22/python-standard-logging-pattern/

Answer (score 1):

A more straightforward implementation of the previous answer might be to use the **DEBUG** variable since this is already available to your code...

```py
if __debug__:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```